# How to decrement the index of a line in an array of strings?

Tags: c#

I am making a code that decrements the line index in an array of strings. My array is like this:

```
1.ExampleFirst\n
  SomeText\n
  SomeOtherText\n
  FinalLine\n\n

2.ExampleSecond\n
  SomeText\n
  SomeOtherText\n
  FinalLine\n\n
```

and so on. The lengths of the lines are not the same.
I want the text to be like this:

```
0.ExampleFirst\n
  SomeText\n
  SomeOtherText\n
  FinalLine\n\n

1.ExampleSecond\n
  SomeText\n
  SomeOtherText\n
  FinalLine\n\n
```

I have made this code:

```
int s = 0;
                                   
 while(s < lineCounter.Count())
   {
 if (int.TryParse(lineCounter[s].Substring(0, 1), out v) == true && lineCounter[s] != "\n") 
    {
      int m = int.Parse(lineCounter[s].Substring(0,1));
      lineCounter[s].Remove(0, lineCounter[s].IndexOf(".")).Insert(0, (m - 1).ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(lineCounter[s]);
     }
 else
       Console.WriteLine(lineCounter[s]);
       s++;
```

The "if" is executed only when the line contains the number and when the line is not a new line. The else is executed to write the other lines in the array.(I'm using console.writeLine to see the results. I know I have to change that part)
When I execute this code, I get the following exception in the "if" statement:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

To me this means that "if" is executed even when the new line between the last line of the first text block and the first line of the second text block is encountered. I can't explain why. Help please!

Comment: You mean the `0` and `1` are part of the text?

Comment: would have been nice if you would have provided a compilable code that would produce your problem ... i was unable to reproduce it, but below you will find a working sample code based on your code fragment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `dotIndex` with combination of `string.Remove()` and `string.Insert()` may do the trick.

```
string[] lineCounter = new string[]{
    "1.ExampleFirst\n",
    "  SomeText\n",
    "  SomeOtherText\n",
    "  FinalLine\n\n",
    "2.ExampleSecond\n",
    "  SomeText\n",
    "  SomeOtherText\n",
    "  FinalLine\n\n"
};

for (int i = 0; i < lineCounter.Count(); ++i) {
    int dotIndex = lineCounter[i].IndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex < 1) //must be at least in the position of 2 or above
        continue;       
    int lineIndex = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(lineCounter[i].Substring(0, dotIndex), out lineIndex)) { //if can be parsed
        lineIndex--; //decrement lineIndex
        lineCounter[i] = lineIndex.ToString() + lineCounter[i].Remove(0, dotIndex);
    }
}
```

I prefer to use `for-loop` to make the loop more definite, but you could change that to `while`/`do`.

This works fine in my PC. Output:

[image]

Edit:

All the results should be in the lineCounter. If you want to see them along the function, you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineCounter.Count(); ++i) {
    int dotIndex = lineCounter[i].IndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex < 1) { //must be at least in the position of 2 or above
        //Print here
        continue;       
    }
    int lineIndex = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(lineCounter[i].Substring(0, dotIndex), out lineIndex)) { //if can be parsed
        lineIndex--; //decrement lineIndex
        lineCounter[i] = lineIndex.ToString() + lineCounter[i].Remove(0, dotIndex);
    }
    //Print here also
}
```

Comment: with this code it's true that you decrement the lineIndex, but the statement if (dotIndex < 1) //must be at least in the position of 2 or above
you skip writing the lines that do not contain an index. The result is like this for me: 0.ExampleFirst 1.ExampleSecond. So I cannot see the other lines that do not contain the lineIndex

Comment: They are all in the lineCounter. If you want to "see" them alongway with the loop, however, do something before `continue`. I update the code for your reference. You may also just as well print all of them after the whole loop finishes, because the lines are all updated in the lineCounter array.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Thank you! ;)

Comment: Ok, great. Glad to hear that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want this:

```
string[] lineCounter=new string[]{
"1.ExampleFirst\n",
"  SomeText\n",
"  SomeOtherText\n",
"  FinalLine\n",
"\n",
"2.ExampleSecond\n",
"  SomeText\n",
"  SomeOtherText\n",
"  FinalLine\n",
"\n"
};
int v = 0;
int s = 0;

while (s < lineCounter.Count())
{
    if (int.TryParse(lineCounter[s].Substring(0, 1), out v) == true && lineCounter[s] != "\n")
    {
        int m = int.Parse(lineCounter[s].Substring(0, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(lineCounter[s].Remove(0, lineCounter[s].IndexOf(".")).Insert(0, (m - 1).ToString()));
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(lineCounter[s]);
    s++;
}
```

Comment: I want it like this:                                                                                                          0.ExampleFirst\n
  SomeText\n
  SomeOtherText\n
  FinalLine\n\n

1.ExampleSecond\n
  SomeText\n
  SomeOtherText\n
  FinalLine\n\n

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be having issues with empty lines on the string array.
Maybe something like this works for you.

```
IEnumerable<string> ShiftIndexes(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
    foreach (string line in lines) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && char.IsDigit(line, 0)) {
            int dotPos = line.IndexOf('.');
            int index = int.Parse(line.SubString(0, dotPos));
            yield return (index - 1).ToString() + line.SubString(dotPos);
        }
        else
            yield return line;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
string[] shiftedLines = ShiftIndexes(originalLines).ToArray();
```